# Render menu twice

Tags: 8, routes

I'm looking for a possibility of rendering the same menu twice, once on the regular place, and another for mobile on a completely different place in my layout, with a completely different structure.

I was looking at JavaScript, but would rather do it with PHP and Twig

Comment: Why don't you just add the menu block twice on `/admin/structure/block`?

Comment: That was my first bet, but the thing is that it's the same menu (same items) but with a different structure, the menu override `menu--menuname.html.twig` is the same

Answer (score 1):

1) Add the menu block a second time (@/admin/structure/block). Give it a specific machine name (eg. main_menu_mobile).

2) Create a second menu template (derived from menu.html.twig) and give it a specific name (eg. menu--main-mobile.html.twig).

3) In your theme, implement a new preprocess hook for blocks and assign another template to your menu:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  // Use another template for the main mobile menu.
  if ($variables['elements']['#id'] === 'main_menu_mobile') {
    $variables['content']['#theme'] = 'menu__main_mobile';
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems good for me. I am implementing this. But i want to know is this a right way to implement menu twice? Or I should follow any other better way? Because if mobile menu disabled from admin, then we would not have mobile menu in pages.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a custom page-template for your site. And you are using the block-system for rendering your regions. So you may have a region called header with your menu in it.

```
<div class="regular-menu">
  {{ page.header }}
</div>
<div class="mobile-menu">
  {{ page.header }}
</div>
```

let me know if I got your question correctly.

Comment: won't work, I need a different structure for my html elements of my mobile menu

Comment: Ok so you really want to know how to render your menu with a custom structure and not how to place the drupal-rendered menu twice in your template?

Comment: no both, I have a correctly working menu which I need to keep, but I need a second menu, structured and rendered differently for mobile, but with the same menu items from the already rendered menu

Comment: If you want to change the structure of your menu you should have a look here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Menu!menu.api.php/group/menu/8#sec_rendering
in Drupal 7 I did this once with http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21core%21includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data/8
but I am not sure this will work in Drupal 8, too.